# How to create Task with 'Related To' field?

Tags: tasks

I want to create Task with 'Related To' (WhatId) field, where the type is 'Product'. But salesforce always says that malformed_id.

`$fields = array (
    'STATUS' => 'IN PROGRESS',
    'PRIORITY' => 'NORMAL',
    'WhoId' => 'xxxx',
    'SUBJECT' => 'My Subject',
    'WhatId'    => 'MXD, // Existing Product code
    'Type'      => 'Download'
);`

In case, if i gave AccountId. it works well, but need to insert 'Product Code'.

--
Update:

I found the solution:

I get the WhatId from 'Product2' table.

`$product_response  = $Connection->query("SELECT Id from Product2 WHERE ProductCode='CUSTOMPCODE'");
$data      = (array) $product_response->records;
$whatid    = $data[0]->Id[0];`

after getting $whatid, then submitted to sales-force:

`$fields = array (
    'STATUS' => 'IN PROGRESS',
    'PRIORITY' => 'NORMAL',
    'WhoId' => 'xxxx',
    'WhatId' => $whatid,
    'SUBJECT' => 'My Subject',
    'WhatId'    => 'MXD, // Existing Product code
    'Type'      => 'Download'
);`

it works well!

Thanks for who helped.

Comment: You could put your solution as an answer. You're allowed to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the "Product Code" field when associating the task to the product directly. It must be a unique 15- or 18-character identifier. If you are attempting to use an "upsert" command, you could use an External ID. See the documentation for [upsert](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_upsert.htm) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

WhatID can be ID of a related Account, Opportunity, Campaign, Case, or custom object.
Please find  the [link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_task.htm)

Comment: It can also be a product, as well, even though the documentation doesn't explicitly state this.